# How can i call resgen in a bat file if the file is edited?

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a resource file using resgen.exe only if the file is edited.
I've found a way to do it, and i need to loop through all the Language available.

This is my script.

```
@echo on

echo ------------------------------
echo -- Starting a run of resgen --
echo ------------------------------

Set resourcesPath=%~1Resources\
Set configuration=%~2
Set platform=%~3

set landingPath=%~1bin\%configuration%\Resources\

echo %landingPath%

IF exist %landingPath% ( echo %landingPath% exists ) ELSE ( mkdir %landingPath% && echo %landingPath% created)

set obj[0].Resource="%landingPath%Strings.en-GB.resources"
set obj[0].Text="%resourcesPath%Strings.en-GB.txt"
set obj[1].Resource="%landingPath%Strings.ru-RU.resources"
set obj[1].Text="%resourcesPath%Strings.ru-RU.txt"
set obj[2].Resource="%landingPath%Strings.es-ES.resources"
set obj[2].Text="%resourcesPath%Strings.es-ES.txt"


FOR /L %%i IN (0 1 2) DO  (

    for %%x in ("%%obj[%%i].Text%%") do set date_of_filenameTxt=%%~tx
    for %%x in ("%%obj[%%i].Resource%%") do set date_of_filenameRes=%%~tx

    ECHO %date_of_filenameTxt:~0, 16%
    ECHO %date_of_filenameRes:~0, 16%

    IF "%date_of_filenameTxt:~0, 16%" == "%date_of_filenameRes:~0, 16%" call :same

    call :notsame

    :same
    (ECHO "No Copy for the :" %%obj[%%i].Text%% )
    call :end

    :notsame
    "%resourcesPath%resgen.exe" %%obj[%%i].Text%% %%obj[%%i].Resource%%

    :end

)
```

The problem is on getting the string from the obj[], how should be the sintax?
i've found if i do as below, it works.

```
call echo resource = %%obj[0].Resource%%
```

Comment: Do not `call` a label inside of the loop. Put the labels outside the loop, and why the spaces in the variable substitution strings?

Comment: The first thing I would advise, right at the top of the script, is to validate that your script has received at least three arguments, and that those arguments are valid strings for the file and directory objects they are supposed to represent. If those arguments are not received, and/or are not valid, then your code should perform some action based upon that, before proceeding with the rest of the code. BTW, you have a typo, additional trailing double-quote character on line `17`

Comment: thanks, @Gerhard i will move it outside. can you be more specific on the variable substitution are you referring to?

Comment: the issue is that i cannot retrive the path from the obj.
if i do

    echo %%obj[%%i].Text%% ==>%obj[0].Text%
if i do 
call echo resource = %%obj[0].Resource%% ==> "c:\xx\yy"

how should i format that to feed the set?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The task could be done much easier with the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
echo ------------------------------
echo -- Starting a run of resgen --
echo ------------------------------

set "resourcesPath=%~1Resources\"
set "configuration=%~2"
set "platform=%~3"

set "landingPath=%~1bin\%configuration%\Resources\"

if exist "%landingPath%" echo "%landingPath%" exists.& goto ProcessFiles
mkdir "%landingPath%"
if exist "%landingPath%" echo "%landingPath%" created.& goto ProcessFiles
echo ERROR: "%landingPath%" could not be created!& goto EndBatch

:ProcessFiles
for %%I in ("%resourcesPath%Strings.*-*.txt") do (
    set "RunResgen=1"
    for %%J in ("%landingPath%%%~nI.resources") do if "%%~tJ" == "%%~tI" set "RunResgen="
    if defined RunResgen "%resourcesPath%resgen.exe" "%%I" "%landingPath%%%~nI.resources"
)

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

The outer **FOR** loop searches in the directory `Resources` for non-hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `Strings.*-*.txt`. There could be used also the wildcard pattern `Strings.*.txt` or the pattern `Strings.??-??.txt`.

For a found text file there is first defined the environment variable `RunResgen` with string value `1` whereby the value does not matter.

Next is executed one more **FOR** processing the resource file in landing `Resources` directory. If that file does not exist at all, `%%~tJ` expands to an empty string which means the **IF** condition compares `""` with something like `"10.11.2021 19:00"` and so the condition is not true. If the appropriate `.resources` file exists, its last modification time is compared with the last modification time of the `.txt` file. If the two file time stamps are equal, the environment variable `RunResgen` is undefined for the next **IF** condition because of no need to run `resgen.exe` for this pair of text and resources files.

The second **IF** condition checks the existence of the environment variable `RunResgen` and if this variable still exists because of `.resources` file does not exist at all or has not the same last modification time as the `.txt` file, the executable `resgen.exe` is executed with the two file names.

Please note that the file date/time format depends on the country setting of the used account. On my Windows machine the date/time format is `dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm` and for that reason the simple string comparison works with these sixteen characters plus the two surrounding quotes taken also into account on comparing the two strings.

`resgen.exe` must create the `.resources` file with last modification date/time explicitly set to last modification date/time of the `.txt` file or this code does not work at all.

There is usually used on Windows the archive file attribute do determine if a source file was modified since last processing it. But I suppose this is not possible here as one `.txt` file could be used for multiple `.resources` files for multiple configurations and platforms (wherever the environment variable `platform` is used in real batch file).

Well, the main code could be even more optimized by using just following single line:

```
for %%I in ("%resourcesPath%Strings.*-*.txt") do for %%J in ("%landingPath%%%~nI.resources") do if not "%%~tJ" == "%%~tI" "%resourcesPath%resgen.exe" "%%I" "%landingPath%%%~nI.resources"
```

The executable `resgen.exe` is executed on `.resources` file not existing at all or its last modification date/time is different to the last modification date/time of the `.txt` file.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `mkdir /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the operator `&` to execute always a **GOTO** after an **ECHO**.